# C++ how to pass the parameter to the one of nested function?

Tags: c++, function

Suppose I have a simple C++ program.

```
Function_C()
{
    /*pass;*/
}
Function_B()
{
    Function_C();
}
Function_A()
{
    Function_B();
}
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    std::cin >> x >> y;
    Function_A();
}
```

The question is: If I want to use the input `x` and `y` in the `Function_C`
(say do the comparison), I need to pass the `x` and `y` to the `Function_A` and then to the `Function_B`, last to the `Function_C`,which makes me to add the parameter into the `Function_A` and `Function_B` just because of `Function_C`. It seems the bad code:(

So, kind Stack overflowers, can anyone offer better idea?

Comment: No, that's the way to do it. What you *can*  ask yourself is why `Function_B` would want to call `Function_C` if it doesn't know anything about `x` and `y`.

Comment: @Shawn Xu  The reason of the bad code is that the function C requires two arguments but the function B does not deal with the arguments. So it is just a bad design. The code in main that reads x and y should be in the function B.  That is the design is logically inconsistent. You could change the function sequence calls in main the following way function_A(); function_C(); And the function_B should not call the function_C.

Comment: If you want a quick fix, just change the scope of x and y and make them static to the module, that way they are visible to all functions in the module.

Comment: What do you think `pass;` does? It's generally considered polite to post code that actually compiles, and this won't. (And if you've genuinely defined a dummy variable called `pass` somewhere just so you can use it in no-op expressions, please... don't.)

Comment: @underscore_d Oh, thanks for reminding, I actually don't know the C++ feature as same as the python `pass`

Comment: @SPlatten just out of curiosity- how do you make something static to the module (without making it a global?) thanks :)

Comment: Exactly the same as a global declaration but with the static keyword, which means the global is only visible to the scope of the module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not necessarily bad code - there's even a name for it which somewhat legitimsies the pattern: *parameterisation from above*. (Acknowledge @Paul Evans). And it's superior to using global variables.

Object orientated programming can obviate this though. A solution based on the formulation

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    void Function_C(){/*use x and y*/}
    void Function_B(){Function_C();}
    void Function_A(){Function_B();}
};

int main(){
    int x,y;
    std::cin >> x >> y;
    Foo f{x, y};
    f.Function_A();
}
```

might scale up better.

Comment: ... and then the object is a kind of context for that handful of functions. I can see scaling issues, but this actually looks nice in simple cases.

Comment: Is it okay to use `struct` as a function block without assigning it a actual meaning?

Comment: @ShawnXu: If its meaning will not be obvious in a few months' time then it ought to be adequately documented. But there's nothing wrong with using a class to solve these kind of problems.

Comment: You know what I did

Answer (score 5):

That's probably what you want to do and it's a pattern called parameterisation from above.  Certainly giving `x` and `y` global scope is what what you want to avoid.

Comment: If I upvote this, can I borrow the term for my answer ;-) ?

Comment: By all means, no need to upvote just say it was from my answer :)